# How to post a complex JSON object to cURL request in java

Tags: java, json, curl, http-post, google-fit

I wanted to post a JSONObject to **https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataset:aggregate**

AND My JAVA code using HttpPost

```
 String AccessToken = "ya29.Glv7A7pTaXdXn8EIHlMnGDBMt34OB72bmKowLFxVM7w7MTu7PRqVoBq7eGd0ljMtOk5aDM6y9WkCDdgZ113rzSzXQe6CZV3UXuNvkzWesAl6CfJoA2IZ9U2C9BaG";
    JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject jobj3 = new JSONObject();
    jobj3.put("durationMillis", 86400000);
    JSONObject jobj2 = new JSONObject();
    jobj2.put("dataTypeName", "com.google.step_count.delta");
    jobj2.put("dataSourceId", "derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps");
    JSONArray jar = new JSONArray();
    jar.add(jobj2);
    jobj.put("aggregateBy", jar);
    jobj.put("bucketByTime", jobj2);
    jobj.put("startTimeMillis", 1487721600000L);
    jobj.put("endTimeMillis", 1487772000000L);

    System.out.println("jobj" + jobj.toJSONString());

    String ApiUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataset:aggregate?access_token=" + AccessToken;
    HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    try {
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(ApiUrl);
        httpPost.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + AccessToken);
        httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(jobj.toJSONString()));
        //sets a request header so the page receving the request
        //will know what to do with it
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + ApiUrl);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("line" + line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception at getDataFromUrl ,error is " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

and its giving me error

```
 {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"invalidArgument","message":"Bad Request"}],"code":400,"message":"Bad Request"}}
```

referred to https://developers.google.com/fit/scenarios/read-daily-step-total

I am new in this can anybody help me?

Comment: First: It's usually a bad idea to post your access/secret to a public forum.

Comment: This has limited time validity so don't worry

Comment: You're either making a mistake in the call or the payload. Try loading the payload from a file containing content that you know is correct. If that works, the problem is in your payload. The error seems to indicate this. Then, compare the output of jobj to the known good.

If the known good doesn't work, then your call is incorrect. Print your headers before sending and compare to those in Postman. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are POSTing incorrect JSON.
The JSON generated by your code:

`

```
{
  "endTimeMillis": 1487772000000,
  "startTimeMillis": 1487721600000,
  "bucketByTime": {
    "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps",
    "dataTypeName": "com.google.step_count.delta"
  },
  "aggregateBy": [
    {
      "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps",
      "dataTypeName": "com.google.step_count.delta"
    }
  ]
}
```

`

According to the specifications, the `bucketByTime` should be for example `"bucketByTime": { "durationMillis": 86400000 }`

It seems that you are not adding the `jobj3` variable in your code to the payload at all, which would contain the correct `bucketByTime` value.

Comment: OMG I didn't notice that silly mistake.Thank you very very much........